# Print angular version in the azure build pipeline

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to print the angular version of the project in the build pipeline.
We are using azure devops and yml for the pipepline configurations

I could able to read the "@angular/core" key from root package.json using powershell task but its not the angular version the project is using. So any idea to get the angular version in the pipepline is greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you share your pipeline yaml and other relevant config?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular CLI, just try to add a command line task or PowerShell task to run the command `ng --version`

[image]